# Reuse a Perl IO::socket::ssl client

Tags: perl, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to lighten a part of my code where I was user an LWP::UA 
To acces a Rest API using a SSL Layer.
I'm trying to achieve the same result with the bare IO::Socket::SSL module.
It work great on the first call with something like this :

```
    my $SSLSocket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
                PeerHost => $server,
                PeerPort => "https");
    print $SSLSocket "GET /restapi/json/v1/resources?AUTHTOKEN=$token HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    while(<$SSLSocket>){
           $response = $_;
     }
    $resources = $json->decode($response);
```

But when I'm trying to reuse this socket I'm getting no awnser

```
my $SSLSocket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
                    PeerHost => $server,
                    PeerPort => "https");
print $SSLSocket "GET /restapi/json/v1/resources?AUTHTOKEN=$token HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
 while(<$SSLSocket>){
        $response = $_;
        }
 $resources = $json->decode($response);
 print $SSLSocket ,"GET /restapi/json/v1/resources/3138/accounts?AUTHTOKEN=$token HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
 while(<$SSLSocket >){
     $response = $_;
  }
 close($SSLSocket );

my $accounts = $json->decode($response);
```

The second read is empty.
Since I cannot use the recv or send method I'm a bit lost.
Is there any way to not open a new SSL Socket on each request ?
Thank you for you answers.

Comment: Please speak real HTTP on the socket and not something which you assume HTTP is from looking at a few examples. If you really want to implement a "lighter" thing read the relevant standards. But I assure you, that you probably will not end up with a lighter implementation.

Comment: OK, I'll use the LWP module, But I'm still interesed in how to awnser back once you've started to read on your socket. Thanks'

Comment: I suggest you read the relevant standards, especially the part how the length of the HTTP body is specified. And you should also learn more about basic socket programming, especially how close of the socket is determined and that if a socket is closed you will not be able to read or write anymore data.